# How to make a 2d numpy array from an empty numpy array by adding 1d numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I'm trying to start an empty numpy array with `a = np.array([])`, but when i append other numpy arrays (like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and `[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]` to this array, then the result im basically getting is
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`.

But what i want as result is: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]`

Comment: `np.array([a,b])`?

Comment: Empty and append work for lists.  Don't try to copy that model with arrays.  Lists have one dimension, you want a 2d array.  `np.array([])` is not an 'empty' array  Pay attention to ita dimension.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to keep adding lists to your np.array. In that case, you can use something like `np.vstack` to "append" the new lists to the array.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
np.vstack([a, [7, 8, 9]])

>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: this is what i get when i try this on an empty numpy array, ```ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 8```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`np.c_[]`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html), especially if `a` and `b` are already 1D arrays (but it also works with lists):

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

>>> np.c_[a, b]
array([[ 1,  9],
       [ 2, 10],
       [ 3, 11],
       [ 4, 12],
       [ 5, 13],
       [ 6, 14],
       [ 7, 15],
       [ 8, 16]])
```

It also works "multiple times":

```py
>>> np.c_[np.c_[a, b], a, b]
array([[ 1,  9,  1,  9],
       [ 2, 10,  2, 10],
       [ 3, 11,  3, 11],
       [ 4, 12,  4, 12],
       [ 5, 13,  5, 13],
       [ 6, 14,  6, 14],
       [ 7, 15,  7, 15],
       [ 8, 16,  8, 16]])
```